# What semantic notions underlie ex/in-tēnsiō with the logical meanings of ex/in-tension?

Tags: etymology, philosophy-terms

1. How did 'ex/in-tēnsiō'  semantically specialize to mean the logical meanings below?
2. 'ex/in-tēnsiō'  obviously share the same root, and differ merely in prefixes. Does the difference in prefix explain their meanings?
3. Does the difference in prefix explain why  'ex/in-tēnsiō' didn't mean the opposite? Why didn't 'ex/in-tēnsiō'  mean «in/ex-tēnsiō» respectively?
4. To wit, why doesn't EXtension signify 'qualities or attributes that the term *connotes*'?
5. Why doesn't INtension signify 'members of the class that the term *denotes*'?

Source: Hurley, P. *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (2014 12 ed, but ∃ [2017 13 ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305958098)). p. 92 Middle.

> The previous section of this chapter explored the cognitive meaning of language in
>   general. The cognitive meaning of terms comprises two kinds: intensional and extensional. The **intensional meaning**, or **intension**, consists of the qualities or attributes
>   that the term *connotes*, and the **extensional meaning**, or **extension**, consists of the
>   members of the class that the term *denotes*. For example, the intensional meaning of
>   the term “cat” consists of the attributes of being furry, of having four legs, of moving
>   in a certain way, of emitting certain sounds, and so on, while the extensional meaning
>   consists of cats themselves—all the cats in the universe. The term connotes the attributes and denotes the cats.
>     The intensional meaning of a term is otherwise known as the **connotation**, and the
>   extensional meaning is known as the **denotation**. *Intension* and *extension* are roughly
>   equivalent to the more modern terms *sense* and *reference*, respectively. Also, note that
>   logic uses the terms *connotation* and *denotation* differently from the way they are used
>   in grammar. In grammar, *connotation* refers to the subtle nuances of a word, whereas
>   *denotation* refers to the word’s direct and specific meaning.

[Etymonline on 'intension (n.)'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=intension) :

> c. 1600, "action of stretching;  increase of degree or force,"
>   from Latin *intensionem/intentionem* (nominative *intensio/intentio*) "a stretching, straining," figuratively "exertion, effort," noun of action
>   from past participle stem of *intendere* in its literal sense of "stretch out, strain" (see [intend](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=intend&allowed_in_frame=0), and compare [intention](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=intention&allowed_in_frame=0), which has the figurative sense).
>
> [ [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97473?redirectedFrom=intension#eid) : ]        **Etymology:** < Latin *intensiōn-em* stretching, straining, noun of action from *intendĕre* to stretch: see [intend n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97441#eid220110), [intense adj.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97466#eid224758), and compare [intention n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97492#eid229279), which is etymologically a doublet of this.

Comment: The body of your question seems to be asking about why intension/extension are used. In that case, you should ask in one of the two English Stacks.

Comment: I must concur with @cmw. I am pretty sure (although I have no references at hand) that *in/extensionality* was first used as a term of the art of logic in English-language writings of R. Carnap, and this would set the *terminus post quem* for the term usage to 1935. If that's the case, the *in-/ex-* distinction is pretty much the same as that in the modern English language, and has probably nothing to do with its original nuances significant to the Roman mind.

Comment: This question seems to be about intension and extension, not about *intensio* and *extensio*. Therefore I agree with the others that it is off topic. Nevertheless, the question could be interesting for this site if you asked it from a Latin point of view (eg. comparing the English pair intension-extension with the Latin one *intensio-extensio*).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks! Do you mind editing my question please? This was your brilliant idea, so you  ought get the credit!

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal How does it look now? Questions often work best when kept concise and to the point. It would help if you could look into the dictionary definitions of these two Latin verbs yourself and specify what puzzles you. You can write a new paragraph of three sentences explaining that, but probably not more. The Etymonline quotes are mostly distracting; a simple link is enough.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I've created a new question with your edit: thanks! Meanwhile, I've tried to edit this to clarify it. Is it on-topic now?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal I think it's on topic now, as it is about Latin, at least mainly. But it's of course not my decision; everyone here is free to vote as they please and decide what they like.

Comment: It is clear and legible now! +1

Answer (score 8):

I will keep this answer about Latin only.
For developments in other languages, please ask on another language site.
The philosophy or linguistics sites might also be options for related questions.

> 1. How did 'ex/in-tēnsiō' semantically specialize to mean the logical meanings below?

This happened after Latin.
For example, in physics we have [intensive and extensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) coming from those same Latin words.
The meaning is quite different from the one you quote, and your quoted text mentions that the terms work differently in logic and grammar.
**Therefore it is safe to say that in scientific terminology words derived from *intendere* and *extendere* do not have any fixed meanings but depend greatly on context and convention.**

Both the physical terms and the ones you quote were inspired by the Latin words, but not taken from their then current meaning.
When a new concept is created, often an old word is taken and given a new purpose.

> 2. 'ex/in-tēnsiō' obviously share the same root, and differ merely in prefixes. Does the difference in prefix explain their meanings?

No.
The same prefix can modify the meaning of a verb (like *tendere*) in many different ways.
You cannot deduce the meaning of a prefixed verb from the simplex verb and the prefix.
You can have a decent guess, but at least nuances will be a little off.
This is the same as with English phrasal verbs; the preposition can change the meaning wildly, in a way that is not immediately related to the meaning of the preposition.

> 3. Does the difference in prefix explain why 'ex/in-tēnsiō' didn't mean the opposite? Why didn't 'ex/in-tēnsiō' mean «in/ex-tēnsiō» respectively?

Whether they are opposites is a matter of taste.
I am more familiar with physics, so let me comment on that example.
There are essentially two ways a thermodynamic property can behave when objects are combined.
One of them is called intensive, the other extensive.
This makes it reasonable to treat them as opposites, although they are more accurately the two alternatives.

The pair *in-/ex-* is commonly recognized as an opposite pair or as a pair of alternatives.
The pair of "in" and "out" makes a clear pair for either kind of use.
Therefore it makes sense to define the opposite or alternative of *ex*-something as *in*-something.
In the physical case, I could argue for the choice as it has been made or switching the prefixes.
I am not familiar with the original argument for the choice; perhaps one term was introduced earlier and the other one later by analogy.

I assume the logical pair of terms is similar.

> 4. To wit, why doesn't EXtension signify 'qualities or attributes that the term connotes'?

> 5. Why doesn't INtension signify 'members of the class that the term denotes'?

This sounds like an arbitrary choice of nomenclature to me.
And in my experience it is often most useful to take definitions as given and the go and work with them.
Of course the rationale behind the choice is interesting, but it is secondary to the subject matter itself.
It is important to get this order of precedence right; otherwise you fall victim to the etymological fallacy.

Why the terms ended up having this meaning is a question about the history of logic — or any other scholarly field where they appear — not a question of Latin.
The semantic reasons you are looking for lie outside Latin.